# Fast and easy matrix operations in C++ on two dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

So I've read about several C++ libraries (such as Armadillo and Eigen) that are great for matrix operations. But do any of these support two-dimensional arrays? For example something like this:

```
double[][] arr;
// fill arr
// ...
Matrix m(arr);
// create another Matrix a
// do for example m.a
```

Preferably without deep-copying the data in arr.

Thank you.

Comment: Or, you can just fill up the matrix

Answer (score 1):

In Armadillo you can use your matrix, without any copy.

From Armadillo documentation.

> mat(aux_mem*, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = true)
>
> Create a matrix using data from writable auxiliary memory. By default
>   the matrix allocates its own memory and copies data from the auxiliary
>   memory (for safety). However, if copy_aux_mem is set to false, the
>   matrix will instead directly use the auxiliary memory (ie. no
>   copying). This is faster, but can be dangerous unless you know what
>   you're doing!

for example you can do

```
double mem[4][6];
mat H(&(mem[0][0]), 4, 6, false);
```